# IPV6 connection to IPV4 TOS option

Tags: ios, sockets, ipv6, qos

could you help me?

So problem is QOS On IPV6 socket when it connect to IPV4 server

I can't set transport options on package

```
self.socket = socket(PF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, 0); // Create UDP Socket
int on = 1;

setsockopt(self.socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_NOSIGPIPE, (void *)&on, sizeof(int));

int off = 0;
        setsockopt(self.socket, IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_V6ONLY, (void *)(&off), sizeof(off)); // Disable IPV6 Only

int option = 46;
// set QOS option
setsockopt(self.socket, IPPROTO_IP, IP_TOS, (void *)(&option),sizeof(option));  // IPV4
setsockopt(self.socket, IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_TCLASS, (void *)(&option),sizeof(option)); //IPV6
```

But when i see packages to IPV4 DSCP is 0

[image: Client IPV4 DSCP]

Server send me correct DSCP 
[image: Server IPV4 DSCP]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your kernel doesn't implement the mapping of IPv6 TCLASS to IPv4 DSCP.

The V6ONLY=0 option is mostly a hack to allow servers to accept both IPv4 and IPv6 connections on a single socket. I'm not surprised that only the bare minimum of options is implemented.

Your best option is probably to contact the kernel developers to see if they want to implement the mapping...

Comment: Tnx, this IOS Platform app run on iPhone

Comment: In that case the kernel developer is Apple, good luck contacting them... :(